# how to launch a url in IE for windows mobile6.5

Tags: mfc, windows-mobile

how to launch url from code in IE .

My application is for windows mobile6.5 and i am using VS2008.

Answer (score 0):

Call [ShellExecuteEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa923541.aspx) with the URL and the default browser will open.

If you want to specifically target a browser, call [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885182.aspx) with the browser path (\windows\iexplore.exe) and your destination URL as the command line.

Comment: hi ctacke... thanx for reply.. i tried your option.. but its not working... can u give me an example ? i mean how to pass parameter to ShellExecuteEx() ?